# What happened to Laravel's redirectTo() method?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

We can override this property to redirect users after login in LoginController:

```
protected $redirectTo = '/home';
```

And here is the statement from documentation:

> If the redirect path needs custom generation logic you may define a
>   redirectTo method instead of a redirectTo property:
>
> protected function redirectTo() { 
>       // }

But it always redirects to `'/home';` whatever the condition is.

```
protected function redirectTo()
{
  if (Auth::user()->role==0) {
    return '/volunteer';
  } else {
    return '/donor';
  }
}
```

*If a method exists it'll use it, otherwise the property will be used.* But it looks like property is being used even if the method exists.

However overriding `authenticated()` or `sendLoginResponse()` function works fine.

```
protected function authenticated()
    {
      if (Auth::user()->role==0) {
        return redirect('/volunteer') ;
      } else {
        return redirect('/donor');
      }
    }
```

What is wrong with `redirectTo()` method there? Here is the [GitHub source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7212b1e9620c36bf806e444f6931cf5f379c68ff/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php#L96) to these methods.

I'm using **Laravel version 5.3.28**.

Comment: Did you try overriding  `redirectPath()` instead of `redirectTo()`

Comment: @Troyer did you mean it inside `redirectTo() ` method?

Comment: @Troyer neither `$this->redirectTo = '/volunteer'` nor overriding `redirectPath()` works. but, it is fine with overriding `authenticated()` method with same code.

Comment: Found this: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/17092 but no more information, seems something is not working well, probly you found one bug, I will test :)

Comment: I assume you are changing the redirectTo in your AuthController.  

Do you have a middleware that's overriding your AuthController's     protected $redirectTo = '/'; function? I created an Authenticate middleware that I use for all redirects related to authentication.  It overrides the protected $redirectTo function. 

It sits outside the authentication package which allows me to upgrade without concern of overwritten code in the Authentication libraries.

Comment: Have you tried this instead of overriding it? Try `return redirect()->to('/volunteer')` if you want it to redirect to a specific url. Also try `redirect()->action('SampleController@index')` or `redirect()->routes('sample.add')`.

Comment: @Nelson i need oto verride because redirect path requires custom generation logic.

Comment: @Dom i have a middleware but it isn't overriding redirectTo()  method.

Comment: @SanzeebAryal Can you please provide all the code in your `AuthController` ? Make sure you added `use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;` + inside the class `use AuthenticatesUsers;`

Comment: @Troyer I haven't changed anything vital there, and i'm sure all the traits are there and `authenticated()` and `sendLoginResponse()` from the same trait are working fine.btw i'm using v5.3.28.

Comment: Couldn't install your Laravel version because is not available anymore, I'm happy you already found the problem, I was checking the repo too but didn't see it! Good job :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is the `redirectPath()` method in src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/RedirectsUsers.php in **Laravel v5.3.28**

```
public function redirectPath()
{
    return property_exists($this, 'redirectTo') ? $this->redirectTo : '/home';
}
```

In the later versions **5.3.29 and above**. This was changed in file with commit:

[Add auth redirect path generation method (#16896)](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/794b260746d7a3bdf8b691bb1e5187716bb21685#diff-80421ddeeadb2389b6ea2a2d00e92a86)

```
 public function redirectPath()
 {
     if (method_exists($this, 'redirectTo')) {
         return $this->redirectTo();
     }
     return property_exists($this, 'redirectTo') ? $this->redirectTo : '/home';
 }
```

**So this part of documentation applies for Laravel version 5.3.29 and later only**

> If the redirect path needs custom generation logic you may define a
>   redirectTo method instead of a redirectTo property:
>
> protected function redirectTo() { // }

---

**Solution for v5.3.28**

To make `redirectTo()` method work in v5.3.28, manually add this in `redirectPath()` method in src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/RedirectsUsers.php.

```
if (method_exists($this, 'redirectTo')) {
    return $this->redirectTo();
}
```

Comment: It is simplier to override redirectPath()

Comment: @Leonid yes. you're right. But, the question is why is `redirectTo()` method not woking as stated by documention?  rather than what might be other solutions?

Comment: ive the same problem on laravel 5.4,5.5 and adding this part didnt solve the problem...

Answer (score 7):

**Simple solution**

Override `redirectPath()` instead of `redirectTo()`.

Using raw string return:

```
protected function redirectPath()
{
  if (Auth::user()->role==0) {
    return '/volunteer';
  } else {
    return '/donor';
  }
}
```

Or overriding `redirectPath()` to the Laravel 5.3.**29** `redirectPath()` version and then your `redirectTo()` method will work.

```
public function redirectPath()
{
  if (method_exists($this, 'redirectTo')) {
   return $this->redirectTo();
  }     
  return property_exists($this, 'redirectTo') ? $this->redirectTo : '/home';
}
```

**Why redirectTo() is not working**

Tested overriding the `redirectPath()` or `redirectTo()` method in `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php` on a clean Laravel v.5.3.29 + default Auth, they work as expected.

**Example of redirectTo() method**

Documentation says:

> If the redirect path needs custom generation logic you may define a redirectTo method instead of a redirectTo property.

So, the function should look something like this:

```
protected function redirectTo()
{
    if(condition) {
      return "/your/path";
    } 
    return "/your/secondpath";
}
```

Comment: Override `redirectPath()` is not working either, i've tested it and i'm sure of that.

Comment: looks like something is wrong with redirectPath() actually, overriding `sendLoginResponse()` is also fine.https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7212b1e9620c36bf806e444f6931cf5f379c68ff/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php#L96

Comment: I was wrong. actually overriding redirectPath() is fine. Earlier i used `return redirect('/volunteer');` but it returns the path directly.so it should be `return '/volunteer';` But, yes. overriding `redirectTo()` method functionality is added after v5.3.29. and documentation is somehow wrong but it is still great. you may rollback your edit.

Comment: @SanzeebAryal I think now is more accurate, I just added the possible solutions. :)

Answer (score 1):

`redirectTo` redirects users that complete login or registration. Users who are already logged in and try to register or log in again will be redirected by `app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php`

```
if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
    return redirect('/home');
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But the question is not about the alternatives. Anyway, It was only the docs came earlier than available version.

Answer (score -1):

I think the issue comes from the web.php routes. I problem went away after I set the default '/' route to point to the login page.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect(route('login'));
});
```