# Laravel 5.3 redirectTo method not working

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I've overridden the **redirectTo()** mehod in **LoginController**
as stated in [Laravel authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication)

but when a user logs in, it doesn't redirect to my custom path.

Here's the [LoginController](http://pastebin.com/agSSCekK)

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think its redirectPath. Once try it out once check this [commit](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/794b260746d7a3bdf8b691bb1e5187716bb21685#diff-80421ddeeadb2389b6ea2a2d00e92a86)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it's still not working

Comment: Once go through this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42024477/what-happened-to-laravels-redirectto-method/42066235)